# Inno setup error "Required parameter "Filename not specified"

Tags: inno-setup

Here is the script for silent installation of MySQL. This is the error I got even after mentioning the file name. Please help me in resolving this.

```
 [Setup]

 AppId={{10943279-F8A1-4B36-8505-8C366B1CE577}
 AppName={#MyAppName}
 AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
 ;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
 AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
 AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
 AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
 AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
 DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
 DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
 OutputDir=C:\Users\DIVYA\Desktop
 OutputBaseFilename=DBInstallationsetup
 Compression=lzma
 SolidCompression=yes

  [Languages]
  Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

  [Tasks]
   Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}";                    GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

   [Files]
  Source: "C:\Users\DIVYA\Desktop\DBInstall.exe"; DestDir: "{temp}";       Flags: ignoreversion
  Source: "I:\demo\mysql-installer-community-8.0.12.0.msi"; DestDir:  "{temp}"; Flags: ignoreversion
  Source: "I:\demo\vcredist_x64.exe"; DestDir: "{temp}"; Flags: ignoreversion
  Source: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\*"; DestDir: "{temp}";    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
   Source: "D:\database.sql"; DestDir: "{temp}"; Flags: ignoreversion
   [Icons]
   Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
   Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

   [Run]
```

; Installing MySQL installation package, which by default goes to C:\Program Files\MySQL\
; /qn also makes msiexec go quiet and unattended.
        Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters: "/i""{tmp}\mysql-installer-community-8.0.12.0.msi"" /qn";
        StatusMsg: Unpacking Mysql 8.0.12.0 installation;
        Flags: runhidden

```
    Filename: "C:\Program Files(x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for    Windows\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe";
    Parameters: " --action=install -t=Custom --config=mysql-server-8.0- win32:passwd=password --product=mysql-server-8.0-win32 --catalog=mysql-8.0-win32 --nowait";
    StatusMsg: Installing MySQL Server;
    Flags: runhidden

     ; Quite self explanatory, we just add mysql service to services currently running on the pc
     Filename: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe";     Parameters:" --install";
     WorkingDir: {app};
     StatusMsg: Installing MySQL Service;
     Flags: runhidden

     ; Starting the service
      Filename: net.exe;
       Parameters: start mysql;
       StatusMsg: Starting MySQL Server;
        Flags: runhidden
         Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait  postinstall skipifsilent
```

[image: Error Screen]

Thanks in Advance.